# Calculate Mean value per each category using scala and spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe and im running the following query

```
sportsData.groupBy("category").agg(count(lit(1)).alias("numberOfRecords")).show(false)
```

output

```
+---------------+---------------+
|category       |numberOfRecords|
+---------------+---------------+
|football       |1              |
|tennis         |2              |
|cricket        |2              |
+---------------+---------------+
```

I have to find mean value for each category. For that I know I can run the agg mean function after grouping by category. but since numberOfRecords column is not a real column in my dataFrame i am unable to get the mean. How should I proceed?

Comment: why don't you try `sportsData.groupBy("category").agg(mean("value"))`?

Comment: value can't be resolved.

Comment: This question is pretty unclear. You want to calculate the mean for which column? There are several questions here on how to calculate the mean per group.

Comment: @blackbishop I want to get the mean for each category using noOfRecords column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved from the below query

```
sportsData.groupBy("category").agg(count(lit(1)).alias("numberOfRecords")).toDF().groupBy("category").agg(mean("numberOfRecords")).show(false)
```

output will be as follows

```
+---------------+--------------------+
|category       |avg(numberOfRecords)|
+---------------+--------------------+
|football       |1.0                 |
|Tennis         |2.0                 |
|cricket        |2.0                 |
+---------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: This is just the same result as what you already have in the question? The mean of a single value will be the same value.